# Socket.IO Server-Server Communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, socket.io

We are using Socket.IO to communicate real-time statistics to connected browsers; however due to the architecture of a system we are building we want to allow both browsers and ***other nodejs servers*** to subscribe via Socket.IO for statistics. Would it be possible for me to create something like a custom transport for communicating via TCP to another Socket.IO server that had subscribed?

We want to continue to use Socket.IO's built in support for channels and subscriptions, but provide server-server via node.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted on Socket.IO's [GitHub Issues Page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/818) and got an answer there. Looks like I will be using [Hook.IO](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io) to do what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this, since Hook.IO is no longer a thing?